# Confused about multi-threading in a loop for C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Captured Variable In Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/c-sharp-captured-variable-in-loop)

I am pretty new to multi-threading programming.
When I ran the code below and only the last child got executed.
Can some one tell me what happened?
Thank you very much.

```
private void Process()
{
    Dictionary<int, int> dataDict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    dataDict.Add(1, 2000);
    dataDict.Add(2, 1000);
    dataDict.Add(3, 4000);
    dataDict.Add(4, 3000);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in dataDict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ready for [" + kvp.Key.ToString() + "]");
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(kvp.Value, kvp.Key));
    }

private static void DoSomething(int waitTime, int childID)
{
    {               
        Console.WriteLine("Start task [" + childID.ToString() + "]");
        Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
        Console.WriteLine("End task [" + childID.ToString() + "]");
    }
}
```

---

Output

---

```
Ready for [1]
Ready for [2]
Ready for [3]
Ready for [4]
Start task [4]
Start task [4]
Start task [4]
Start task [4]
End task [4]
End task [4]
End task [4]
End task [4]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By using the loop variable in your lambda, all of the effectively refer to the same variable, which is the last item of your dictionary at the time they run.

You need to assign the loop variable to another variable local to the loop before passing it to a lambda. Do this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in dataDict)
{
    var pair = kvp;
    Console.WriteLine("Ready for [" + pair.Key.ToString() + "]");
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(pair.Value, pair.Key));
}
```

EDIT: It seems this little pitfall is fixed in C#5. That's why it might work for others ;) See comment by labroo

Comment: people should really explain why they downvoted, seems like a reasonable explanation to me

Comment: Why the downvote, I dont know if this is the solution, but it is a valid change....... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: Was wondering, too. Can't see anything wrong with my answer.

Comment: btw, what Botz3000's answer is implying is that all of the threads run...however, by the time they get the chance to run, kvp == 4

Comment: I figured that too, but I just don't understand why.

Comment: for that, you'll need to read up a bit about how lambda functions capture scope

Comment: **Dreteh**, read the link posted by **labroo** to understand. By using the loop variable in your lambda, all of them effectively refer to the same variable, which is the last item of your dictionary at the time they run.

Comment: You should explain the problem and solution if you are going to duplicate an answer from an already established question

Comment: Thank you guys. Lobroo's link explain all.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent that behavior by assigning kvp to a local variable in the for loop and pass the variables fields Key and Value to the DoSomething method.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that too, but I just don't understand why.